# How to fetch data of sold nft from my NAMI wallet through api?

Tags: cardano-address, cardano-api, cnft.io

I am using "https://api.opencnft.io/1/asset/{asset}/tx" which gives the buy price and timestamp of an NFT, I have to fetch the data(Sold Price, Timestamp) of the NFT when it is sold then how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

I recently gave an example of this in [another question here](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/10906/which-api-can-give-the-buy-price-and-sold-price-of-nft-of-cardano-blockchain/10911#10911). The sold price will be the latest transaction for that asset.

Comment: so, through "https://api.opencnft.io/1/asset/{asset}/tx " which is giving me  " sold_at" timestamp and using "https://cardano-mainnet.blockfrost.io/api/v0/assets/{asset}/transactions" which  also gives timestamp and the immediate next block timestamp's hash  from previous  opencnft api .... so  could this give me the sold price of the nft when I sold it ?

Comment: Yes, though the api won't call it an obvious name like "sold_at." It will simply be the output_amount quantity in lovelace.